# How can I send a Unix signal to an app running under debug mode within Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, unix, signals

I'm making a command-line app. I want to test `Ctrl+C` or `SIGUSR1`, but I couldn't find any way to send some signal to them.

I tried `kill -s INT <pid>`. I got `<pid>` with `ps -A | grep $PROGAM_NAME`  But this causes debugger popup, and doesn't call my signal handler. Of course I installed custom signal handler with `signal()` function.

Why this doesn't work? And How can I send some signal to the process under debugging?

Answer (score 0):

get the pid from the application, write it to a file (so you can find it) and then run the kill